# How accurate is GeoDistance?

Tags: bugs, geodesy

**Bug introduced in 8.0.1 or earlier and fixed in 10.0.0**

---

Two years ago I tried an evaluation copy of *Mathematica*.  I reported
various inaccuracies in the `GeoDistance` routine to which I never
received any fix.  Could someone check whether `GeoDistance` is any more
accurate now?  Thanks.

Here are the problems I reported on June 20, 2011:

```
                                     Mathematica   Correct     Error
GeoDistance[{30, 0}, {-30, 180}]  -> 19928486.7   20003931.5  -75444
GeoDistance[{0.4, 0}, {0.4, 180}] -> 19915473.0   19915472.0       1
GeoDistance[{0, 0}, {0.5, 179.5}] -> 19936426.5   19936288.6     138
```

Comment: For completeness: which reference frame are you using for the "correct" versions? By default, *Mathematica* uses `"ITRF00"` as the reference frame, and `GeoDistance[]` uses Vincenty's method (`Method -> "Vincenty75"`) for distances.

Comment: The "correct" results were calculated for the GRS80 ellipsoid (a = 6378137, f = 1/298.25722210088271), i.e., the reference ellipsoid used by ITRF00.  Using WGS84 gives the same results (when rounded to the number of digits given here).

Comment: Interesting... if I crank up the setting of the option `"InverseMaxIterations"` for `GeoDistance[]`, I still get the incorrect results for the first two, but I get something much nearer to the "correct" value for the third example. If you want to debug what's happening, you might want to set the option `"InverseVerbose"` to `True`.

Comment: The `"Vincenty75"` method has known limitations; so if `GeoDistance` is
still using this method, the results will be suspect for nearly
antipodal points.  Incidentally, Vincenty himself recognized the
problems with his method and supplied a fix that went some way to curing
the problems.

Comment: There's an alternative setting for `Method`, `"ExtendedNewtonRaphson"`. It fails on your first example, but returns results close to the "correct" ones for the other two.

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know.  However, it does make you wish that
Mathematica would get rid of its three slightly flaky methods for
GeoDistance and instead use one that just worked!

Comment: Might I propose posting an implementation of an alternative algorithm (e.g. the improved Vincenty method) as an answer to your question? :)

Comment: With "I reported" you mean you sent a bug report to wolfram support? Or did you report it somewhere on a forum?

Comment: I submitted it Wolfram support on 2011-06-27 and got a reply (TS 22876) saying it had been forwarded to "the appropriate people in our development group".  I did a follow-up a few days later with a similar reply.  That was the last I heard about the matter (and I couldn't pursue it further since my trial license ran out).

Comment: Maybe you could write a *Mathematica* implementation of the methods in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z)... :)

Comment: @J. M. the link is broken.

Comment: I hope this is only a temporary situation as we paid $3k so that anyone could access this paper.  If you continue to have problems, you can download the preprint version of the paper from http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.4448

Answer (score 12):

From the information provided by @J. M., the answer to my question is
that `GeoDistance` has the same problems as it did 2 years ago.  I
implemented (in C++) some improved algorithms for geodesics in 2009
which are described in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z).  The benefits relative to `GeoDistance` are:

- accurate to round-off for $|f| < 1/50$;
- always converges;
- computes ellipsoidal areas (and some other properties).

Subsequently I've ported the algorithms to C, Fortran, Python, MATLAB,
and JavaScript (see http://geographiclib.sf.net).  The port to Java is in progress (it'll be ready in less than a month).  I'm not in a position to write a *Mathematica* version because I no longer have access to *Mathematica*.  However, if someone else wants to take the lead on this, I would be happy to assist.  Alternatively, perhaps it's easier to interface *Mathematica* to the C or Java version (Java would be better since it presents a class interface)?

Comment: It hopefully shouldn't be too hard. OTOH, since *Mathematica* has explicit support for elliptic integrals, one might be able to use those instead of the truncated Fourier approximations in your paper.

Comment: The formulation in terms of elliptic integrals is given [here](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/geodesic.html#geodellip) and implemented in the C++ library (no other languages at this point).  For WGS84 with C++, the elliptic integral method is roughly 2 times less accurate (more accumulated round-off error) and 2 times slower.  On the other hand, elliptic integrals are good for any flattening (I've checked $1/100 < b/a < 100$).

Comment: "roughly 2 times less accurate" - depends on the implementation, I'd say. I note that you're using the imaginary modulus formulation (the Earth's oblate); I'm sure you're aware that [those expressions can be reformulated](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7.E5) so that the moduli are real and within $[0,1)$, which should make for more stable evaluation. OTOH, the formulae also involve $D(\phi,k)$ and the elliptic integral of the third kind, and those are indeed very difficult to deal with numerically, so I'd guess that's why you're not getting full accuracy from the elliptic integral formulation.

Comment: If push comes to shove, it might be more expedient to reformulate in terms of Carlson's symmetric integrals; at least, in that formulation, computing the two special functions I mentioned earlier is less bothersome.

Comment: I use Carlson's symmetric integrals; this is important because the
expressions in terms of Legendre's integrals involve big cancellations.
The use of an imaginary modulus is a non-issue once the integrals have
been converted to Carlson's forms.  I don't find the increased error too
surprising.  With the series solution, round-off can be very well
controlled.  It is difficult to maintain this accuracy with the more
general formulation (however, I admit that I didn't try really hard).
In any case, the accuracy is still very good -- about 25 nanometers
for WGS84.

Answer (score 11):

I've completed the implementation of my geodesic algorithms in Java.
Documentation (including download information) is available at

http://geographiclib.sf.net/html/java

I gather that it's easy to call Java code from Mathematica.  If someone
would be kind enough to post instructions on how to do this, I would be
happy to include this in the documentation.

This implementation uses series expanded to 6th order in the flattening.
This gives results accurate to round-off (using double precision) for
|*f*| < 1/50.  There are two possible extensions which may be of interest
to Mathematica users:

1. The solution in terms of elliptic integrals (to deal with highly
   eccentric ellipsoids of revolution); this is currently implemented in
   the C++ and Maxima versions.
2. The use of arbitrary precision arbitrary precision arithmetic;
   this is currently implemented in the Maxima version.  (Since version 1.37, released on 2014-08-08, this capability is also available in the C++ library.)

**ADDENDUM:**  The Java library is now available from Maven Central (since 2015-04).  To use it include the following dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.geographiclib</groupId>
  <artifactId>GeographicLib-Java</artifactId>
  <version>1.42</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I just checked 10.1, and the results are accurate. If you have a copy of it, would you check it to see if it meets your needs?

Comment: This is good to hear.  Unfortunately, I don't have Mathematica, so I can't check for myself.  From the documentation it looks like the old Methods options, Vincenty75, Robbin61, ExtendedNewtonRaphson, have disappeared.  Presumably the function is now using some reliable method?

Comment: I know a lot of work went into making sure it was correct, but what exactly, I don't know.

Comment: Dear cffk, I have some plans to implement the numerical evaluation of the Carlson integrals in *Mathematica* in the next few weeks; this might be useful to you for your accurate implementation of the geodesic distances. If you're interested, drop me a line.

Comment: I believe that Mathematica 10 is using elliptic integrals to solve for
the geodesic.  However, a naive formulation gives errors for geodesics
which graze a pole.  To check if this is a problem, try GeoDistance and
GeoDirection for (1) {40,0} to {40,179.9999999999} and (2) {40,0} to
{89.9999999999,97}, (3) {89.9999999999,97} to {40,0}.  The right answers
are: (1) 11144873.397924414760 m, 0.00000000007766797 deg, (2)
5572436.698963568587 m, 0.00000000012982366 deg, and (3)
5572436.698963568587 m, -82.99999999991642394 deg.

Comment: Dear J. M., I have no access to Mathematica at present.  However, Carlson's symmetric integrals are definitely the way to go for solving geodesics (and I have this implemented in C++ with MPFR).

Comment: The "next few weeks" took longer than I would like, but [I've finally implemented it](https://github.com/tpfto/Carlson).

Answer (score 8):

This appears to be fixed. Mathematica v10 matches your "Correct" values for all three examples.

Comment: David, thank you for following up on this. Indeed, v 10.2 matches the "Correct" values as well.

Comment: Could you also check that GeoDistance and GeoDirection for (1) {40,0} to {40,179.9999999999} and (2) {40,0} to {89.9999999999,97}, (3) {89.9999999999,97} to {40,0}? The right answers are: (1) 11144873.397924414760 m, 0.00000000007766797 deg, (2) 5572436.698963568587 m, 0.00000000012982366 deg, and (3) 5572436.698963568587 m, -82.99999999991642394 deg.  Thanks.

Comment: They are slightly different. (1) gives 11144873.39798774 m and 0.00000000007791086747713033 deg, (2) gives 5572436.698995231 m and 0.0000000001298175198786149 deg, and (3) gives 5572436.698995231 m and -82.9990873583041 deg. Max relative error on distance is 5E-10 %, on direction it is 0.3 % for example (1).

Comment: Thanks for these results.  A good way of assessing them is to do the
direct geodesic calculation starting at point 1 with the computed
distance and azimuth and seeing how far you are from point 2.  The
results are (1) 63 um, (2) 32 um, and (3) 77.9 m.  The last result is
disappointingly large.  The possible problems in the algorithm are (a)
poor numerical hygiene when doing spherical trigonometry and (b) a
failure to use Cayley's transformation of the elliptic integral for the
longitude see https://books.google.com/books?id=Zk0wAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA333

Comment: I received a response from Wolfram Tech Support that they have forwarded an incident report to the developers regarding this.

Comment: For comparison, the errors using GeographicLib (the C++ version using double precision) are about 4 nm (nanometers).  There's no reason why Mathematica shouldn't be able to match this.

Comment: @cffk Case (3) is fixed in 10.4.0.